# How to dockerize my new VPS server?

Tags: docker, vps, webmin

Currently I have a VPS server running CentOS with DirectAdmin panel on it.
I managed everything from the panel and easily created new hosting packages for my client.
As a programmer I demand much from my server, so since it is a managed VPS it consumes so much time to communicate with my provider.

So I want to order a unmanaged Ubuntu VPS and want to get started with docker.
All my clients have to move to the new server as well.

What is best practice for dockerizing your VPS?
I think I'm going to use Webmin and Virtualmin, do you install them outside of docker containers?
Or can I build a docker image from the whole old VPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the steps to dockerize VPS:

- install Docker Engine and Docker Client on the CentOS server
- using the "docker run" command instantiate Docker Containers
- install Webmin and Virtualmin on the CentOS server (outside of the Containers)
- now manage those Containers with Webmin and Virtualmin

Caveat: Docker Containers are really designed to run one app per container. Here you are trying to emulate VMs that run many apps using Containers. But I think, this can be done.

Disclaimer: I have not done this before, but I have worked with Containers enough to foresee that this can be done.

Cheers,
Joe

Comment: Thanks Joe, the CentOS is my old VPS. So why installing docker on the old server?

Comment: @user3411864 Sorry I meant install docker on the new Ubuntu server.